# How to remove div if img src is empty with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to figure out how to remove a div if the img src is empty.

I've searched on stackoverflow, but most are all jq based. Can someone help in vanilla javascript?

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper ">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img
             src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526947425960-945c6e72858f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTN8fHByb2R1Y3RzfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80"
             alt=""
             class="imgCard"
             color=""
           />
       </div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img
             src=""
             alt=""
             class="imgCard"
             color=""
           />
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can probably use an if statement like this: `!HTMLImageElement.src`. If it's empty, then change the div display style to none like this: `HTMLDivElement.style.display = 'none'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can do this

```js
const swipers = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide');

swipers.forEach(e => {
  const imgSource = e.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
  if (imgSource.trim() === '') {
    e.remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="swiper-wrapper ">
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526947425960-945c6e72858f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTN8fHByb2R1Y3RzfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="" class="imgCard" color="" />
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="" alt="" class="imgCard" color="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all images which are child of `.swiper-slide` class and check if their have `src` attribute different than an empty string like this

```js
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide img");

imgs.forEach(item => {
  if (item.getAttribute('src') === "") {
    item.parentNode.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="swiper-wrapper ">
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526947425960-945c6e72858f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTN8fHByb2R1Y3RzfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="First image alternate text" class="imgCard" color="" />
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="" alt="Second image alternate text" class="imgCard" color="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to trim the source also, as there may be a chance that it contains space there which will not be empty